# 3D interpolation along two dimensions only

Tags: matlab, interpolation

There is something I don't understand about interpolation in MATLAB. I want to interpolate along two dimensions of a three-dimensional array.
Take

```
M = rand(3,3,5);
x = 1:3;
y = 1:3;
xx = linspace(1,3,10);
yy = linspace(1,3,10);
```

If I run

```
interp1(x,M,1)
```

I get back a `1x3x5` matrix, which was interpolated along the first dimension. Now I want to get a `1x1x5` matrix which was interpolated along the first two dimensions, sort of by doing

```
interp2(y,x,M,1,1)
```

which, however, produces an error. I could do

```
interp2(y,x,M(:,:,1),1,1)
```

and loop over the third dimension, but I am looking for a more elegant solution which avoids the loop and works similar to `interp1` above.

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html): *`Vq = interp2(X,Y,V,Xq,Yq)` returns interpolated values of a function of two variables at specific query points using linear interpolation.* You have a function of 3 variables, hence the error.

Comment: So you're saying I need the loop?